# How to insert value to missing region in a fastq file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics

Understand fastq file which has 4 important lines.

```
Line starting with @ contains the sequence identifier.
Line containing the DNA sequence.
Line starting with + (plus sign) indicating the beginning of the quality score line.
Line containing the quality scores corresponding to the DNA sequence.
```

I have a corrupted fastq.gz file where a `+` sign is missing in the file. For example, `zcat sample.fastq.gz`

```
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:3539:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NTTCTAAATTGAAGGAAGAACAAGACAAAGAAATACTGGAGACAGAAATTGAATCAAACCATCCTAGAGTGGCTTCTGCTTTACAAGACCA
+
#AAAAJJJJFJJJAJFFAFAJJJJJ-<JJJJJJA-7JFJJJJAJFJFFFJAJJ----JJ-----FJFF-<AF<FFJ-FFFJJJ<FJA<J-F
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:6461:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NGGGCTGTGAACCAGGCCATCGGGCAAGTGATCTGGCACAGCCAGGACAACAGAGCAGTCTTCCTCTGTGACCACAGGGTTGCCTTTGCAG
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
```

The third read in the file has missing `+` file.

the expected output is :

```
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:3539:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NTTCTAAATTGAAGGAAGAACAAGACAAAGAAATACTGGAGACAGAAATTGAATCAAACCATCCTAGAGTGGCTTCTGCTTTACAAGACCA
+
#AAAAJJJJFJJJAJFFAFAJJJJJ-<JJJJJJA-7JFJJJJAJFJFFFJAJJ----JJ-----FJFF-<AF<FFJ-FFFJJJ<FJA<J-F
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:6461:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NGGGCTGTGAACCAGGCCATCGGGCAAGTGATCTGGCACAGCCAGGACAACAGAGCAGTCTTCCTCTGTGACCACAGGGTTGCCTTTGCAG
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
```

I tried like:

```
zcat sample.fastq.gz | awk 'NR%4==0 {print "+"} {print}' | sed 's/^\+$/+/g' > corrected_file.fastq
```

But it gave me:

```
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:3539:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NTTCTAAATTGAAGGAAGAACAAGACAAAGAAATACTGGAGACAGAAATTGAATCAAACCATCCTAGAGTGGCTTCTGCTTTACAAGACCA
+
+
#AAAAJJJJFJJJAJFFAFAJJJJJ-<JJJJJJA-7JFJJJJAJFJFFFJAJJ----JJ-----FJFF-<AF<FFJ-FFFJJJ<FJA<J-F
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:6461:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NGGGCTGTGAACCAGGCCATCGGGCAAGTGATCTGGCACAGCCAGGACAACAGAGCAGTCTTCCTCTGTGACCACAGGGTTGCCTTTGCAG
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
+
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFAs
```

Comment: Does the "Line containing the quality scores corresponding to the DNA sequence." always start with a `#` and no other line starts with a `#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -e '/^@/{n;/^[[:alpha:]]/{n;/^+/!{i\+' -e '}}}' input_file
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:3539:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NTTCTAAATTGAAGGAAGAACAAGACAAAGAAATACTGGAGACAGAAATTGAATCAAACCATCCTAGAGTGGCTTCTGCTTTACAAGACCA
+
#AAAAJJJJFJJJAJFFAFAJJJJJ-<JJJJJJA-7JFJJJJAJFJFFFJAJJ----JJ-----FJFF-<AF<FFJ-FFFJJJ<FJA<J-F
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:6461:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NGGGCTGTGAACCAGGCCATCGGGCAAGTGATCTGGCACAGCCAGGACAACAGAGCAGTCTTCCTCTGTGACCACAGGGTTGCCTTTGCAG
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat file | awk '/^@/{n=0} (++n == 3) && !/^\+/ { print "+" } 1'
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:3539:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NTTCTAAATTGAAGGAAGAACAAGACAAAGAAATACTGGAGACAGAAATTGAATCAAACCATCCTAGAGTGGCTTCTGCTTTACAAGACCA
+
#AAAAJJJJFJJJAJFFAFAJJJJJ-<JJJJJJA-7JFJJJJAJFJFFFJAJJ----JJ-----FJFF-<AF<FFJ-FFFJJJ<FJA<J-F
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:6461:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NGGGCTGTGAACCAGGCCATCGGGCAAGTGATCTGGCACAGCCAGGACAACAGAGCAGTCTTCCTCTGTGACCACAGGGTTGCCTTTGCAG
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
```

or if the "Line containing the quality scores corresponding to the DNA sequence." always starts with a `#` and none of the other lines do then you could alternatively do:

```
$ cat file | awk '/^#/ && (p !~ /^+/) { print "+" } { p=$0 } 1'
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:3539:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NTTCTAAATTGAAGGAAGAACAAGACAAAGAAATACTGGAGACAGAAATTGAATCAAACCATCCTAGAGTGGCTTCTGCTTTACAAGACCA
+
#AAAAJJJJFJJJAJFFAFAJJJJJ-<JJJJJJA-7JFJJJJAJFJFFFJAJJ----JJ-----FJFF-<AF<FFJ-FFFJJJ<FJA<J-F
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:6461:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NGGGCTGTGAACCAGGCCATCGGGCAAGTGATCTGGCACAGCCAGGACAACAGAGCAGTCTTCCTCTGTGACCACAGGGTTGCCTTTGCAG
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
@E00592:278:HC7KLCCX2:2:1101:5751:1502 1:N:0:NCATCCTC
NAAAATTCATTCTCTAGGTTCATTACTTGAAGGCCCCTTATGATTAGCAAGGACTTGATTGTCTCAGGACACGGTTTCAATAATAAGTAGC
+
#A<<A-AJJJJFFJJJJJ<7JFFFFAJ-7JJJJJJJ7FF-F-<F<JF77AJJ7FAA-F-<<--<JAJJFJJJFJJ<<JAF<JJFJJFAJFA
```

Just replace `cat file` with `zcat sample.fastq.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'n;n;/+/{n;b};i\+' file
```

If the 3rd line contains `+` read another line and break out.

Otherwise, insert a line before that 3rd line containing `+` only.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using only Bash built-ins:

```bash
zcat sample.fastq.gz | while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    if [[ $LINE =~ ^\+ ]]; then
        SEEN_PLUS=1
    else
        if [[ $LINE =~ ^'#' ]]; then
            if [[ ${SEEN_PLUS:-0} -ne 1 ]]; then
                # Print correction
                printf '+\n'
            fi
        fi
        SEEN_PLUS=0
    fi
    printf -- '%s\n' "$LINE"
done
```

Comment: That would take orders of magnitude longer to run than an awk script (and since the OPs input is gzipped it's a fair bet it's a large file where speed of execution may matter), and it's more code to write, and it's not portable to other shells so there's really no reason to do it AFAIK.